# Construction of a sequence of natural numbers with a limit

Tags: sequences-and-series

Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but I would like to know if it is possible to construct a sequence of natural numbers (besides a constant sequence) which has a limit?

By a sequence of natural numbers, I am referring to a sequence in which $a_k\in \mathbb{N}$ for any $a_k\in (a_n)$, where $k,n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Thank you.

Comment: Such a sequence is eventually constant, since $\mathbf N$ has (usually) the discrete topology.

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with topology yet, can you elaborate on the connection between the discrete topology and and a sequence becoming constant?

Comment: If a sequence converges to a limit $\ell$, for any $\varepsilon>0$, all terms of the sequence, but a finite number, are within $\varepsilon$ of $\ell$, hence within $2\varepsilon$ of each other. If you choose $\varepsilon<\dfrac12$, this means they're (almost) all within $1$ of each other. As they're natural numbers, they must be equal.